# R: how to set p for minkowski distance in pheatmap?

Tags: r, distance, pheatmap

In R, there is a function to generate heatmap with dendrogram, called `pheatmap::pheatmap`. `minkowski` is one of the distance measuring options for `pheatmap` to draw dendrogram. However, how to set the `p` (The power of the Minkowski distance) in function `pheatmap`?

Thanks.

Comment: If you read the documentation more closely you would get the point that @lebelinoz posted. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pheatmap/pheatmap.pdf

Comment: you mean this one? `# Specifying clustering from distance matrix
drows = dist(test, method = "minkowski");
dcols = dist(t(test), method = "minkowski");
pheatmap(test, clustering_distance_rows = drows, clustering_distance_cols = dcols)`

Comment: Exactly. dcols and drows are defined outside of pheatmap.

Answer (score 1):

The Minkowski distance has nothing to do with the `pheatmap` package.  It is part of the `dist` function in the `stats` package.  If you try `?dist`, you'll see that `dist` has a `p` parameter specifically for Minkowski method of taking distance:

```
dist(x, method = "minkowski", p = 2)
```

Comment: My understanding is that `pheatmap` use `dist` function internally to draw dendrogram. However, I couldn't find how to set the parameter `p`, which is in `dist`, in `pheatmap`.

Comment: `dist` is not part of `pheatmap`.  It is from the `stats` package, and I use it when I draw heatmaps using different packages.